# Is there a property to make an Appcelerator desktop application window fixed size?

Tags: javascript, appcelerator

I can't find a property in the API documentation that would make an Appcelerator desktop applications window a fixed size. In other words, I don't want the user to be able to resize the window.

Anyone know if such a property does exist?

Answer (score 0):

in the example on [this](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/desktop/latest/Titanium.UI.createWindow-method) page they just set in the window create params "resizable: false".

these look to be the best options for what you want to do.

```
maximizable: true||false
minimizable: true||false
  closeable: true||false
  resizable: true||false
 fullscreen: true||false
```

below is a call that uses every option

```
Titanium.UI.createWindow({
  id: "propertyWindow",
  url: "app://second_page.html",
  title: "My New Window",
  contents: "<html>foo!</html>"
  baseURL: "app://page_url"
  x: 300,
  y: 400,
  width: 500,
  minWidth: 500,
  maxWidth: 500,
  height: 500,
  minHeight: 500,
  maxHeight: 500,
  maximizable: true,
  minimizable: true,
  closeable: true,
  resizable: true,
  fullscreen: false,
  maximized: false,
  minimized: false,
  usingChrome: true,
  topMost: false,
  visible: true,
  transparentBackground: false,
  transparency: false
});
```